# Difference between 2 tables show some similarities

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm usign two tables in my PHP application, I want all the rows that are in newLista but don't exist in oldLista, both have the same structure

> id | vinculo | tipo_dni | numero_dni | apellido | nombre | fech_nac | sexo | numero_tit | ABM | convenio

I have already trying using RIGHT JOIN but it won't show any results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM newlista a 
RIGHT JOIN oldlista b ON a.numero_dni = b.numero_dni 
WHERE b.numero_dni IS NULL
```

The code that I'm usign is this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM newlista AS a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM oldlista AS b 
    WHERE a.numero_dni=b.numero_dni AND a.apellido = b.apellido 
) 
ORDER BY a.apellido ASC
```

But it keep showing me some persons that have the exact same `numero_dni` and same `apellido`

Comment: Your initial request seems mostly right, if you change `RIGHT JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN` (right join takes all rows from your right table (oldlista) and then "adds" matches found on the left table, so b.numero_dni will never be null, unless it's already null in your oldlista table)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the tables' structure as `CREATE` statements, sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements and the desired result for that sample data.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from newlista
minus
select * from oldlista
```

Comment: It wont work in mysql, which I'm usign, the equivalent would be NOT IN right?

Answer (score 0):

In that case:

```
select * 
from newlista 
where numero_dni not in (select numero_dni 
                         from oldlista)
    and apellido not in (select apellido
                         from oldlista)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you want:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM newlista a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM oldlista a2
                  WHERE a2.numero_dni = a.numero_dni AND a2.apellido = a.apellido
                 )
ORDER BY a.apellido ASC;
```

This is basically your query.

If you are seeing duplicates, it is because the values *look* the same but are not.  Some issues are easy to fix.  Others are harder.  Here are some examples:

- Leading/trailing spaces.  This can be fixed using `trim()`.
- Confused characters, as one and lower-case L or an em-dash versus an en-dash.  Squinting or changing the font might help.
- Hidden characters, such as a backspace that might not show up.
- Characters from an alternative character set that are or look the same.